# MirrorMaker 2 Avro format

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

it is necessary to transfer topics in avro format using MirrorMaker 2. is it possible to override

```
     'key.converter'= 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter',
     'value.converter'= 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter',
```

on avro?

Answer (score 0):

MirrorMaker should keep the data as raw as possible. Always use ByteArrayConverter if you want to 1) speed up the consumption and 2) not introduce issues with round-trip serialization

Avro data is still bytes